# Wordpress Thumbnail add action if no thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress

I was learning how to make my own Wordpress plugin, currently I'm confusion how if there is no thumbnail in the post then I use the default image as thumbnail.
code that I use:

```
add_action( 'the_post', 'mythumb' );
function mythum(){
   if (!has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $defaultthum = "http://example.com/default.jpg"
    echo ('<div class="featured-thumbnail"><img width="150" height="150" src="'.$defaultthum.'" class="attachment-featured wp-post-image" alt="7" title="" /></div>')
   }
}
```

my problem: the default image thumbnail is not in the right position.
see this picture: http://s22.postimg.org/ezt05f59d/Lm_XUp.png
any idea? or the hooks is not the_post?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the hook that you use, it is triggered at the beggining of the post loop. You'll have to check [wordpress hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks_2.0.x) to see if you can use any of them (probably closest to what you need is the_content) but if there is no hook offered where you need it you'll have to create your own [hook](http://archive.extralogical.net/2007/06/wphooks/) / [action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action).